# Sign-in issues with Bot framework

Tags: botframework

I was using bot framework and everything worked fine till one day when I suddenly sarted getting error while trying to sign in.
This is the error that I am getting.
***Sign in failed. CorrelationId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000***
Any help with this will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Our problems are a little different, but I do have the same error message when first time tried to log in on https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new. And after I successfully logged in Azure portal, I can successfully logged onto the botframenetwork. Hopefully this could help.